# Why does the energy of an electron inrease with its shell number inside an atom?

Tags: atomic-physics

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model#Electron_energy_levels):

$ E = \frac{-13.6 Z^2}{n^2} $

the energy of an electron is, well, higher the farer it is away from the core. I found this confusing as I need to put less energy to release an electron when it is on the 5th shell than when it is on the 1st shell. Am I right?
Concluding, one would say "The more energy an electron has the less energy I need to release it".
This wouldn't be the case if "they" didn't introduce the minus sign. It probably has a reason and I'm probably neither the first nor the last who asks about that. But, sorry, I still have to ask: Why did they do that? Why is a minus better than a plus?

Comment: Related: [Why is the total energy of an orbiting system negative?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/172414/9887)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did they do that? Why is a minus better than a plus?

Firstly, understand that when the electron is 'infinitely' far from the nucleus its energy is $0$ (assuming it is also stationary).

But empirically we also know that when an electron 'falls' from a higher orbital ($n=n_1$) to a lower one ($n=n_2$ where $n_2<n_1$) energy is released in the form of a photon emission, so $\Delta E <0$. And indeed:

$$\Delta E=E_2-E_1=-13.6 Z^2\Big(\frac{1}{n_2^2}-\frac{1}{n_1^2}\Big)<0$$

So the choice of sign is correct.

Comment: The higher orbital is $ n_1 $ and the lower is $ n_2 $ ?Despite from that I don't see an argument for the minus at that place?

Comment: That IS the argument: put a plus sign in and you'd get $\Delta E >0$ which is contrary to our experience. It's a convention to ensure that for a 'falling' electron, $\Delta E<0$. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Ah, because otherwise, it would gain energy?

Comment: The convention (universal, not just electrons) is that an energy *loss* is a negative $\Delta$ and a gain is a positive $\Delta$.

Comment: Well, that makes sense, indeed. Confusing but once that is known it makes sense :)